# Page number before Chapter title in the Table of Contents with book document

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, color, memoir

I'd like to configure my table of contents as this, into a book document : the page number (in red color) before the chapter title (in black color).

For example:

```
3    Down the Rabbit Hole
7    The Pool of Tears
15   The Caucus Race and a Long Tale
```

For the configuration of the order, I've seen this answer, which do the job for memoir document but not for book document  :

https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/55669/revisions

The code of this revision :

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% redefinition for the ToC title
\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\HUGE\sffamily#1}

% redefinitions for chapter entries
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\huge\sffamily}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@mychap[3]{%
  \vskip2ex%
  \par\noindent
  \parbox{2.5em}{%
    \hfill{\cftchapterpagefont#2}%
  }\hspace*{3em}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-5.5em-15pt\relax}{%
    \cftchapterfont#1%
  }\par%
}

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Down the Rabbit Hole}
\chapter{The Pool of Tears}
\chapter{The Caucus Race and a Long Tale}
\setcounter{page}{14}% just for the example

\end{document}
```

How can I obtain the same result for a latex book document ?

And can I declare a red color just for page number in the toc ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your output under [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir):

[image]

Here is the output under `book` with the suggested minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft,xcolor}

% redefinition for the ToC title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily}

% redefinitions for chapter entries
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}[1]{\makebox[\cftchapnumwidth][r]{%
  \cftchappagefont
  \raisebox{-.2\height}[0pt][0pt]{\color{red}\chappagenum}\quad}}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\huge\sffamily}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{5.5em}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3ex}% Adjust to suit your needs
\cftsetpnumwidth{0pt}% Not really needed...

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chappagenum}{}
\let\oldl@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \renewcommand{\chappagenum}{#2}%
  \oldl@chapter{#1}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Down the Rabbit Hole}
\chapter{The Pool of Tears}
\chapter{The Caucus Race and a Long Tale}
\setcounter{page}{14}% just for the example

\end{document}
```

[`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) was used to manipulate the ToC-related entries, as it has a user interface that is very similar to what `memoir` provides.